# Docusign Embedded Signing Expiration

Tags: api, docusignapi

We've been testing out using Embedded Signing with our Docusign integration so that clients do not receive an email with each envelope sent to them, instead they would log into a portal which contains links to documents to sign (as some clients do not have an email address, even today!).  However we have noticed that the URLs generated through Embedded Signing expire after 5 minutes.  Is there a way to control how long these URLs are valid for?  Why do these expire when the URLs in the emails do not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an account level setting. DocuSign Support or your Account Administrator can edit this for you.

By default it is set to 300 seconds (5 minutes).

Comment: It's not editable from the user side, it has to be done by a DocuSign employee.

Comment: OK, I will look into that, thanks. It seems like you know a bit about DocuSign. I'm going to post some questions soon about various DS stuff; I'm a little fuzzy about some of its workings, and perhaps I just need to "scratch some things off the list." because they can't be done. Even if this is this case, it would be helpful to know that; along with why a work around may or may not be feasible.