# How can I send an envelope link manually?

Tags: docusignapi

I have an envelope I've created through the API and I set the status of it to sent during creation time so it was never sent to the customer. Then using `receipientViewRequest` I grabbed the link for it and sent that to the customer in an email so they can sign it. However, the link only works once. After the first click/visit, the link expires. Is there anyway to get a link to the envelope that doesn't expire?

Comment: See the related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613175/docusign-embedded-signing-expiration?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signing flow which you are using is called as `Embedded Signing`. In embedded Signing, you need to invite or ask your signer to visit your App, and when signer is ready to sign the document then at that time you should generate the signing URL (on-demand) and ask user to complete the signing. This link is one time use and by default, it expires in 300 seconds if not used. If you want DocuSign to send an email to the signer with your App URL so that signer is redirected to your App when he/she clicks the email link, then you can put your App URL in the `embeddedRecipientStartURL` property of the signer in the API call. By adding this property DocuSign will send an email to DocuSign and on click on Review Documents button, browser will be redirected to your App, once it reaches your App then you can generate embedded Signing URL so that you can host the Signing ceremony.

You should never send this embedded Signing URL link in an email or via any medium. If you want DocuSign to send an email to the signer so that signer can sign the document at any time then you should do `Remote Signing`, this can be achieved by removing the clientUserId for the recipient in your API call.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here's what I did: I include a link to our website, once the customer visits the page I figure out what they're trying to sign and generate the embedded link and redirect them to it. Since that link expires after the first use, this seems like a secure approach.